# How to use wp-ajax in wp-cron

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, javascript, wp-cron

I have create a custom wordpress plugin where i am using wp ajax. In class's __construct i have an action (admin_footer) in order to use wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script following wp [instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

So the flow is something like php -> js -> and again php

Why I am doing that ? To avoid memory limit error. [Here](https://wpshout.com/beyond-avoiding-php-timeout-memory-limit-errors-ajax/) says something nice : "The solution above routes around PHP’s limitations by breaking a single large task into a number of smaller"

Everything works like a charm in backend!

My question is how i can manage this process to work with wp-cron? Is possible for wp-cron to work with js?

I tried wp_schedule_event with my custom hook without success (js never works).

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: What you want to do cannot be done in a single request, even if that request then makes lots of other requests, be  they AJAX requests or any other kind. Unless the entire process can be done in  the time allotted, the maximum time will be reached. You need to break it apart into smaller chunks that can be processed. This approach will never work from a single WP Cron event, this is a dead end

Answer (score 0):

First of all, think about using the [new REST API instead of Admin-AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273758/wp-ajax-vs-wp-rest-api-what-to-use-for-requests-to-the-website-from-outside) in your environment where JavaScript is available.

Now to answer your question: JavaScript isn't available for wp-cron, as these requested solely run on the server and not on some interpreted HTML/JavaScript. So what can you do? Well, just schedule another event if you didn't finish yet (or your separated workload is done).

While [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) is used for recurring events, there is also [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/) which can be used for the "not yet finished" workloads.

Say you want to clean your db daily, a workflow could look like this

1. `wp_schedule_event()` to dail run function `clean_my_db()`
2. Within `clean_my_db()` you create an array `$tables_to_clean = ['posts', 'postmeta']`. Now you call `wp_schedule_single_event()` to run `clean_my_db_table()` and pass each of the tables as argument.
3. `clean_my_db_table('posts')` runs
4. `clean_my_db_table('postemta')` runs
5. etc

To summarize: You have one function called by `wp_schedule_event()` which is a recurring event. Within that you decide to split workloads and run them via `wp_schedule_single_event()` at specific dates/times.

Comment: Hi, i start this plugin using WooCommerce REST API but it was too slow for what I want (sync thousand items from other system ), so i change it to WC_ class. Using new REST API instead of Admin-AJAX how i can avoid php time limit when I'll schedule me job (e.g. sync 10.000 items from other system to wp) ?

Comment: @John478 The answer stays the same: don't sync 10.000 at once, but in small batches over time