# How can i get the same ajax result using WP REST API instead of admin-ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, javascript, rest-api

I have been told that admin-ajax is outdated now and it's better to use REST API instead but I was wondering how can I get the same result of this code which generates a button with a link based on some variables and custom fields using REST API?

also, someone told me that this code is not secure because I'm using HTML response instead of data in ajax but I'm wondering how to use data for this code?

I apologize but i'm still very new to coding

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'simple_amz_link_ajax', 10);


function simple_amz_link_ajax() {   
?>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

             jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                         action: 'getmyfunctionform1',
                         postId: <?php echo get_post()->ID; ?>
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {

                jQuery("#buy_amz_btn_wrap").html(response);

                }

        }); 
    });
</script> 
<!-- end Ajax call to getmyfunctionform1 smc 11-22-2013 -->

<div id="buy_amz_btn_wrap"> Loading ... </div>

<?php
}

// Amazon Simple Button Function

add_action('wp_ajax_getmyfunctionform1', 'myfunctionform1');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getmyfunctionform1', 'myfunctionform1');

function myfunctionform1() { 
    $postId = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $country_code = $_SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
    $de_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, "wccaf_de_asin", true );
    $uk_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );    

    $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';


//////////////////////////////////////////////


if ($country_code=="DE" or $country_code=="DE") {
    $amazon_domain = 'https://www.amazon.de';
    $associate_id = 'bonstato-21';
    $asin = $de_asin;
}

else if ($country_code=="GB" && $uk_asin!=="") {
    $amazon_domain = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk';
    $associate_id = 'bonmedico-21';
    $asin = $uk_asin;
}

///////////////////

global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $postId );
        $type = $product->get_type();
        if( $type == 'simple' && $asin!="" ){   

                // Amazon Link For Mobile       
                ?>
                <script>
                    function amzGo(){
                        window.location='<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/dp/<?php echo $asin ?>/?tag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>';
                }
                </script>
                <?php


        ?>
            <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >  
                <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="amzGo();"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                           
            </div>
        <?php
        }

        else if( $type == 'simple' && $asin=="" ){   
            echo $not_avilable_country;
}


die(); 

} 
?>
```

Comment: You'll find some additional information here: [WP-AJAX vs WP REST API: What to use for requests to the website from outside?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/273758/22534)

Answer (score 1):

You should not listen to what "people tell you" unless you pay them, or they have an undisputed proven authority in the field (known security researcher, wordpress core contributor, etc), same way you probably do not listen to people that tell you that the earth is flat.

The ajax end point is less optimal in performance over wp-json end point, but it is nothing that you are likely to notice as a user unless your site does a lot of use of ajax, and they are neither more nor less secure from each other.

As for returning HTML in a response to ajax request, this is a bad habit but saves development time on both PHP and JS, especially when the HTML changes rapidly, so even here it is not a black and white situation. To have the flexibility of using the response   in different contexts, you should use JSON, but if your ajax request are anticipated to be used in exactly one way, there is nothing horrible about returning HTML.